# Create a bootable RAID 1 in Windows 10/11?

Tags: software-raid, raid-1

I have two NVME 2TB PCIe X 4 and I am using an AMD 5950X.

How do I create a RAID so that it’s bootable for a Windows 10/11 install?

Comment: You'd either use the RAID controller in the UEFI firmware _(if applicable)_, else via a RAID PCIe card _(for example, if AMD offers a built-in controller like Intel does [Intel RST], select RAID as the protocol type in the UEFI firmware and partition as normal IIRC)_

Comment: My ROG X570-I doesn’t offer it. My Intel Laptop does! Can I use a Spanned Volume?

Comment: "Can I use a Spanned Volume?" - Horrible idea. If one of the disks dies you lose everything.

Comment: It seems that it is possible to boot from (a VHDX on) Storage Space, but it might be a bit tricky to set up.

Comment: Is a “Spanned Volume” a software RAID? If it is then forget about that. How would I create a hardware raid using the motherboard I own (ROG X570-I)?

Comment: Software "RAID" (aka fake RAID) and booting don't really mix, FYI.

Answer (score 2):

FYI: Better do not try to make "hardware" RAID with this motherboard. It would be fake-RAID. Also for do it you need to add motherboard RAID-controller driver during Windows installation.

For your case probably better to use Windows software RAID. I recommend you mirror-RAID(1), like in article.

Would be much easier if you'll use MBR partitioning and not to use UEFI.

Here is acticle from Hetzner for both types: https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/dedicated-server/raid/windows-server-software-raid/
There is also the link for MS article with UEFI type.

- *Do not try to make Storage Spaces when you have only 2 disks. It need to dedicate 1 partition for boot.*
- *Fake-RAID and Software-RAID have the same CPU impact.*

---

So, shorter (if you don't need fault tolerance boot):
Install Windows, open disk manager, make clean second disk, convert source disk to dynamic, right click to source volume and pick "add mirror"
[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z89m5.png)